# Attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, spring-data-jpa

I don't know what's special about my issue compared to all the other questions related to one-to-one property mapping but even after looking at those I still can't resolve my DB2 issue here. I have a complex set of entity inheritance and it all works except this one little relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_ITEMS")
public class OrderItem {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ORDER_ITEM_ID")
private OrderCoreItem coreItem;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDER_CORE_ITEMS")
public class OrderCoreItem {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
@GenericGenerator(name = "foreign", strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "orderItem"))
@Column(name = "ORDER_ITEM_ID")
private Long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "coreItem", optional = false)
private OrderItem orderItem;
}


 OrderItem item = new OrderItem();
 OrderCoreItem coreItem = new OrderCoreItem();
 coreItem.setOrderItem(item);
 item.setCoreItem(coreItem);
 orderItemRepo.save(item);
```

I honestly can't see anything else amiss here. Anyone?

Comment: Why are you using @GeneratedValue(generator = "foreign")
@GenericGenerator(name = "foreign", strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "orderItem"))
@Column(name = "ORDER_ITEM_ID") this? id is your primary key in OrderCoreItem.

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal primary key is in OrderItem and the join happens on that key so that OrderCoreItem has a primary key that is the same as OrderItem's. Perhaps I need to do an insert of OrderItem first, retrieve it and then store the OrderCoreItem's? Seems kind of convoluted.

Comment: If I remove the generatedValue annotation I get this error: `ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()`

Comment: I can't save the OrderItem by itself, it's part of a large entity so I would basically have to persist the entire structure first and then come back and add the OrderCoreItem's. There must be a better way.

Comment: Try, @Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) on OrderCoreItem.

Comment: That gives me `could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=ORDERCOREI2_.ID, DRIVER=4.13.127` because I think it's expecting the OrderCoreItem to have a DB2 identity and it doesn't.

Comment: For now I have this working with a hack `@SecondaryTable(name = "ORDER_CORE_ITEMS", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ITEM_ID"))` so I have deleted the OrderCoreItem and placed it's fields into the OrderItem and over the fields created a column annotation like this `@Column(table = ORDER_CORE_ITEMS", name = "CORE_ITEM_ID")` but would like to see if maybe anyone knows a solution that keeps the entities separate.